# Rewrite and redirect this url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite and redirect the following url:

```
/display/0123456789/product-name
```

to

```
/product-name/display/0123456789
```

I tried the following, but its not working for me.

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/display/([0-9+]) /display/([0-9])/([^/]+) [L]

Redirect 301 /display/([0-9+])/([^/]+) /([^/]+)/display/([0-9+])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^display/([0-9]+)/([A-z\-]+) /$2/display/$1
Redirect 301 /display/([0-9+])/([^/]+) /([^/]+)/display/([0-9+])
```

And, an image as tested on [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

[image: ReWrite Rule Test]